# Why the output of the following code is still "Java" even though objects are passed by reference not value?

Tags: java, string

String in Java is a non-primitive data type, because it refers to an object. Still answer is not "JavaJava".

```
class Java 
{ 
    public static void concat(String s1) 
    { 
        s1 = s1 + "Java"; 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String s1 = "Java"; 
        concat(s1);  
        System.out.println("String: " + s1); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: String is Immutable

Comment: What do you think that `concat(s1);` does?

Comment: Java _passes references by value._  That's not the same as pass-by-reference.